# How to solve Linear motion problem

Tags: projectile-motion

At point K a particle which is at rest starts motion when $t=0$ it moves with a uniform acceleration $f_1$ for a period of $t_1$. Then it decelerates by $f_2$ for a period  of $t_2$. Then it accelerates again by $f_1$ afterwards.

prove if $f_2t_2>2f_1t_1$, the particle passes through point K for 2 times?

**My Work**

Since this sum asks about returning to initial position I know that the deceleration $f_2$ continues even after the velocity of particle reached zero causing it to move backwards.

I tried writing an expression for,

Distance Traveled Forward < Distance Traveled Backwards

But this didn't yield the given inequality. Can you please help me to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry couldn't find a related tag. So I put Projectile-motion tag, Because I want to ask this question from MathStack community specifically

Comment: Is $f_2$ also a constant acceleration?

Comment: Yes @Carser its also uniform deceleration